# How to detect leaked Disposable subscriptions in RxJava code?

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks, rx-java, rx-java2

My Android project has **RxJava** onboard. How to check that all `Disposable` resources are being released correctly and it time later after `subscribe()` calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see all ***not*** disposed Rx subscriptions *at the moment*, use [RxDisposableWatcher](https://github.com/andreyfomenkov/rx-disposable-watcher) tool.
Read my post on Medium: [Detect Leaked Subscriptions in RxJava code using RxDisposableWatcher](https://andrey-fomenkov.medium.com/find-leaked-subscriptions-in-rxjava-code-using-rxdisposablewatcher-8c2226dce01c)
**Features**

- **HTML** report with all necessary info:

  - full stack trace where `subscribe()` occurred
  - number of calls
  - observable type
- supports RxJava 2.x and 3.x.

**Example of HTML report**
[image]